# Cannot find installed cask within brews cellar

Tags: homebrew

I am not too familiar with the command line.

I need to find the path where my tex-distribution is installed.

I've used brew to install "mactex-no-gui" (I am running a Mac) via

```
brew install mactex-no-gui
```

Now, I try to find this installed cask:

```
xyzs-MBP local % brew --prefix mactex-no-gui
/opt/homebrew/opt/mactex-no-gui

xyzs-MBP local % ls -halt /opt/homebrew/opt
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  10 me  admin   320B  5 Mär 17:07 .
lrwxr-xr-x   1 me  admin    30B  5 Mär 17:07 gs -> ../Cellar/ghostscript/9.53.3_1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 me  admin    30B  5 Mär 17:07 ghostscript -> ../Cellar/ghostscript/9.53.3_1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 me  admin    23B  5 Mär 17:07 libtiff -> ../Cellar/libtiff/4.2.0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 me  admin    17B  5 Mär 17:06 libjpeg -> ../Cellar/jpeg/9d
lrwxr-xr-x   1 me  admin    17B  5 Mär 17:06 libjpg -> ../Cellar/jpeg/9d
lrwxr-xr-x   1 me  admin    17B  5 Mär 17:06 jpeg -> ../Cellar/jpeg/9d
drwxr-xr-x  31 me  admin   992B  5 Mär 16:45 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 me  admin    22B 14 Jan 21:47 cmake -> ../Cellar/cmake/3.19.3
-rw-r--r--   1 me  admin     0B 14 Jan 21:47 .keepme

xyzs-MBP local % ls -halt /opt/homebrew/Cellar
total 0
drwxrwxr-x   7 me  admin   224B  5 Mär 17:07 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 me  admin    96B  5 Mär 17:07 ghostscript
drwxr-xr-x   3 me  admin    96B  5 Mär 17:07 libtiff
drwxr-xr-x   3 me  admin    96B  5 Mär 17:06 jpeg
drwxr-xr-x  31 me  admin   992B  5 Mär 16:45 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 me  staff    96B 14 Jan 21:47 cmake
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  admin     0B 14 Jan 21:47 .keepme
```

But I can't find it.

P.S.: The installation worked because after the installation I can use `tex` command within terminal.. But `whereis tex` does not have any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the cask definition with:

```
brew edit mactex-no-gui
```

You will find, in the uninstall section, at the end, the list of directories where files are installed:

```
/usr/local/texlive/#{version.major}
/Library/TeX
/etc/paths.d/TeX
/etc/manpaths.d/TeX
```

Comment: Ahhh, thank you very much!! But then, the output of `brew --prefix mactex-no-gui` is a bit confusing..?!